# How can I count the number of JsObjects in a JsValue?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In Play! (2.2-M2) I have a [JsValue](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.2.0-M2/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsArray) similar to:

```
val people: JsValue = [{"name":"Alice","subdomain":"alice","color":"orange"},{"name":"Jorge","subdomain":"jorge","color":"blue"},{"name":"Bob","subdomain":"robert","color":"green"}...]
```

I just want the number of elements in this JsValue. I can get it, clunkily, through

```
(people \\ "name").size
```

but this size calculation sits inside a method that receives JsValues with different content, and `name` won't always be present, like

```
val places: JsValue = [{"country":"UK", "country":"ES", ...]
```

or

```
val things: JsValue = [{"widget":"foo", "price":"1", "widget":"bar" ... ]
```

I'm pulling my hair out, how do I just get the number of elements in these JsValues?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to count the number of objects inside the array, you can map it to a `JsArray`.

`people.as[JsArray].value.size` or `people.asOpt[JsArray].map(_.value.size)`.